# iOS 8 Swift CS193P Calculator Bug Switch Operation

Tags: ios, swift

I just started learning Swift with Stanford tutorial. I have Xcode 6.3.2. 
I'm getting a bug at a `switch` operation and can't understand how to solve it.

I attached a screenshot as well

```
@IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
        let operation = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber{
        enter()
        }
        switch operation{

        case "➕": performOperation {$0+$1}

        case "✖️": performOperation {$0*$1}

        case "➗": performOperation {$1/$0}

        case "➖": performOperation {$1-$0}

        default:break
        }

    }
    private func performOperation(operation : (Double,Double)->Double){
        if(operandStack.count>=2){
            DisplayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(),operandStack.removeLast())
            enter()
        }

    }
```

[image: Xcode Error]

Comment: what bug? The debugger stopped because you have set a breakpoint at that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine, it looks like you accidentally placed a breakpoint in your code, see that *blue-looking* arrow to the left of the *green-highlighted* line?

***Do one of the following:***

- Go ahead and *right click* that and click **Delete Breakpoint**
- Drag and drop that breakpoint into your view controller

*When you do one of the following listed, your program will run smoothly*

Don't worry, you'll start to catch onto these simple fixes and you will be able to get to more coding.

**Check this out for more information about *[Adding, Disabling, and Deleting Breakpoints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html)*.**

Comment: That link on adding, disabling, and deleting breakpoints is broken. :(

Comment: Here is the correct link:  [**Adding, Disabling, and Deleting Breakpoints**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html)

Comment: Try it again, I fixed it :) @DuncanC

Comment: There you go. Works now.

Comment: Ah Right. it is the problem. :) i didnt know its breakpoint thing. Thank you very much

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help. :) @axonlivelabs